# Parlor palm leaves turning brown

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, indoors

I just got a parlor palm from the nursery last week, and placed it in a low-light area in the house, and no watering, since the soil seemed moist at the nursery.
Many of the larger leaves of the plant have turned brown within a week, and the glossy look of the leaves seems to be gone. It's still in the growbag from nursery, haven't yet gone round to potting it. What is going wrong?[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This plant is too wet.  Chances are good it is sitting in water.

- move to high light
- remove from gro pot and transplant to a pot with drainage holes
- do not add stones or any other material to the bottom of the pot

Answer (score 0):

Yes back off water, repot it. Drought is good, over watering in not. Bright indirect sunlight. Mine are huge hope this helps:)

Comment: Hi Penny, welcome to the site.  You may notice that this site works differently.  Its about a question and answers to it.  And we expect each answer to add something new.